# MacOS like lazy provisioned filesystem on Linux

Tags: lvm, hard-disk, ext4

I have always had issues with estimating how to partition a hard disk for the system, media, and other data. Although you can resize partitions more easily with LVM, it still consumes time and forces a particular workflow. I'm wondering how to achieve on Linux such setup as on Mac:

```
df -lh                                                                                      
Filesystem    Size   Used   Avail  Capacity  iused    ifree       %iused  Mounted on     
/dev/disk1s6  932Gi  10Gi   288Gi  4%        488235   9767489925  0%      /                            
/dev/disk1s1  932Gi  615Gi  288Gi  69%       2330515  9765647645  0%      /System/Volumes/Data         
/dev/disk1s5  932Gi  5.0Gi  288Gi  2%        5        9767978155  0%      /private/var/vm              
/dev/disk1s2  932Gi  12Gi   288Gi  5%        222816   9767755344  0%      /Volumes/Macintosh HD - Data
```

so, as you see, all partitions share the size of the whole disk. Can it be achieved with ext4+lvm2? I know lvm2 has some settings related to this and that you can set `tune2fs -m` for reserved blocks percentage, but I'm not sure how.  Can I use this as a safeguard to give priority to the root partition when the disk is almost full?

Comment: I have fixed some formatting and spelling errors, however I can not make sense of "so you see all partitions share size of whole disk.". Edit the question, to make this clear.

Comment: Subvolumes inside a single Btrfs.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

**Btrfs**

Already mentioned in comments, btrfs uses *subvolumes* which share the space on the btrfs filesystem. Default installation with Fedora 33 which uses btrfs by default now:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
...
/dev/vda2        19G  6.4G   13G  34% /
/dev/vda2        19G  6.4G   13G  34% /home
```

So you have a single partition (on system with single disk, btrfs also supports multidisk volumes) with two subvolumes `home` (mounted on `/home`) and `root` (mounted on `/`) that share the partition space.

More about btrfs:

- https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page

**LVM Thin Provisioning**

Instead of creating logical volumes directly in the volume group a special thin pool volume is created and thin volumes are allocated from it. These can be created smaller and will automatically grow or you can create an "overprovisioned" thin pool (=size of the thin lvs is bigger than the pool) and allocate both `/` and `/home` to be the same size as the pool or even bigger.

Thin provisioning is a little bit more problematic when it comes to the space exhausting and you need to make sure to not use more space than actually available because the filesystem doesn't know the space in the pool is used (downside of doing these things on block layer).

More about thin provisioning:

- https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/LVM/en#Creating_a_thin_pool
- https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/lvmthin.7.html

Comment: ZFS is another option.  Very stable and mature. Have used it on all my systems for nearly a decade without a failure. See https://zfsonlinux.org/

Comment: Thx, so basically how those filesystem fail in case if I would use more space than available ? Would BTRFS or ZFS refuse to allocate , can I setup different reserverd blocks with tune2fs for root partition and data partions or tune2fs is ext4 specific ?  Would any of those system store files in RAM until I find free space instead of refusing write ?